# How can I execute a function if multiple fields have specified length with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am writing some JavaScript to manipulate a form. The form originates from Gravity Forms on WordPress so I don't have direct manipulation of the form. I am using Custom HTML to load a JS file. It's working fine, but my question is specific to JavaScript.

I have 3x date fields for MM, DD, and YYYY. I would like to execute a function when all of these fields are completely entered.

Currently, I have this, which I found on another thread and it works for one field's test. It's listening for keyup event and then testing length, and then calling doMyFunction(). The input_9_60_1 is the working ID of the field.

```
document.querySelector('input[id="input_9_60_1"]').onkeyup = function() {
  if (this.value.length === 2) doMyFunction();
}
```

What I need to do is test input_9_60_1, input_9_60_2, and input_9_60_3 for lengths of 2, 2, and 4 respectively, and if all three are true, then doMyFunction(). Is there a simple way of doing this?

I am thinking I need to set some variables for the 3x length values, and then evaluate against all of them on each input's onkeyup event.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an array of selectors and lengths to check against:

```
const inputs = ['#input_9_60_1', '#input_9_60_2', '#input_9_60_3']
  .map(([sel]) => document.querySelector(sel));
const validLengths = [2, 2, 4];
for (const input of inputs) {
  input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    if (inputs.every((input, i) => input.value.length === validLengths[i])) {
      doMyFunction();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I was just writing the exact same thing :-) Except I'd add something like `data-datecheck` in the HTML to every element so that the inputs can be selected instead of listed in a variable

Comment: I like this... though I need to wrap my head around the syntax here.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way: use a global variable: the state of your page. it will keep data on the inputs. e.g.:

```
let state = {
    input_9_60_1: false,
    input_9_60_2: false,
    input_9_60_3: false
}

// Same event for input_9_60_2 and input_9_60_3
document.querySelector('input[id="input_9_60_1"]').onkeyup = function() {
  if (this.value.length === 2) {
    state.input_9_60_1 = true;
    doMyFunction();
  }
}

function doMyFunction(){
  if(state.input_9_60_1 && state.input_9_60_2 && state.input_9_60_3){
    // run your code
  }
}
```

simple and effective

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it myself but please let me know if there's a better way. I'm sure I can shorten this up too...

```
mm_length = document.getElementById("input_9_60_1").value.length;
dd_length = document.getElementById("input_9_60_2").value.length;
yyyy_length = document.getElementById("input_9_60_3").value.length;

document.querySelector('input[id="input_9_60_1"]').onkeyup = function() {
    mm_length = this.value.length;
    if (mm_length==2 && dd_length==2 && yyyy_length==4) {
        doFunction1();
    }
    else doFunction2();
}

document.querySelector('input[id="input_9_60_2"]').onkeyup = function() {
    dd_length = this.value.length; 
    if (mm_length==2 && dd_length==2 && yyyy_length==4) {
        doFunction1();
    }
    else doFunction2();
}

document.querySelector('input[id="input_9_60_3"]').onkeyup = function() {
    yyyy_length = this.value.length;
    if (mm_length==2 && dd_length==2 && yyyy_length==4) {
        doFunction1();
    }
    else doFunction2();
}

function doFunction1() {
    // stuff;
}

function doFunction2() {
    // stuff;
}
```